# How to access component's children during a @PostConstruct method?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to handle all `<p:panel>` components inside the `<h:panelGroup>` in the backing bean. I have bound the `<h:panelGroup>` to a backing bean property. But during the `@PostConstruct` method the property is `null`. During the setter of the property `setPanel()`, the component has no children. If I submit something using a button, then I can get the panel's children.

What do I have to do to get the component's children during the `@PostConstruct` method?

View:

```
<h:panelGroup binding="#{wiz.panel}">
    <p:panel header="one">
        <h:outputText value="primeiro" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel header="two">
        <h:outputText value="segundo" />
        <h:inputText />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel header="three">
        <h:outputText value="terceiro" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel header="four">
        <h:outputText value="quarto" />
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Backing bean

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (getPanel() != null) {
        for (UIComponent comp : getPanel().getChildren()) {
            if (comp instanceof Panel) {
                System.out.println(((Panel) comp).getHeader());
            }
            System.out.println("not a panel child");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("panel is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. The `@PostConstruct` can be invoked long before the component tree is finished building. Rather hook on the `preRenderView` event. At that point the view is guaranteed to be already built. You can attach an event listener method by `<f:event>` in the view as follows:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

Don't forget to remove the `@PostConstruct` annotation from the `init()` method or to rename/split the method if necessary.

Needless to say that this approach is fishy. I suggest to rethink your approach and if necessary ask a new question wherein you state the functional requirement in detail. Perhaps the ultimate answer would be just using plain EL and/or `rendered` attribute.

Comment: The f:event is calling the init method now, but getPanel() has no children yet. Is there another "type" i should try?

Comment: The `getPanel()` method returns just the `panel`, right? (by the way, why not just access the `panel` directly?). What JSF impl/version are you using? It works for me in Mojarra 2.1.4.